# Object detection in binary image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, object-detection, binary-image

This task comes from tracking object on a steady background. So far I was able to remove the background and obtain binary masks like this:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I need to get bounding rectangle of the toy without the cord attached to it (on some frames it's quite thick). Sounds easy enough but I can't think of a good way to do it.

I tried cross-correlation with template of the toy I cropped. It wasn't really nice, plus I needed rectangle to be able to change it's size. And the cord added some mess.

`meanShift()` also didn't show good results because of the cord and occasional noice.

For now I use `findContours()` with some tweaks, but it still produces some weird boundaries on what seems like an okay image.

I keep thinking there must be some more simple and effective solution.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the cord attached, I would simply do a closing followed by an opening. Like that you first reconnect the close points, then you erase the isolated points and cut the cord.

Then you can compute the bounding box with the corresponding MatLab function.

Comment: Once the closing/opening operations are done, some undesired blobs may be remaining. You can "filter" them by them contours properties (for example : you can ignore a blob if it's perimeter or surface is not high enough)

Answer (score 0):

According to your second image, the closing process may remove a big part of the toy (because of the thin border of the toy's body), so (if we can assume that the position of the toy and the cord is always vertical) you should firstly use convex hull, then in "each row of the image" separately, look for the thick objects (based on the fact that the toy's width in all parts are way more than the cord or noisy spots). In each row, every horizontal line that has a length more than the threshold, keep that line, otherwise remove it. In this way you would reconstruct just the convex hull of the toy and now you can fit a rectangle to it easily.